# How to set nav bar to be full and not windowed in html and css?

Tags: html, css

[image: Screenshot]Hey guys i have been trying to make this header or nav bar full screen without padding, but not able to. Tried making padding 0 but couldnt. Please help me guys as i have been trying this since a long time. Cheers

Here is my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Shopifter</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div> <a href="index.php"> Home </a></div>
                <div align="center"> <h2>Welcome to Shopifter</h2></div>
                <div align="right">
                    <button> Sign in</button>
                    <button> Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        </body>
        </html>

body {
        background-color: grey;
    }

    header {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 0;
    }

    header nav {
        margin: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #fff;
    }
```

Comment: You need CSS, also you didn't show your CSS. Have width: 100%; Also what do you mean by full screen?

Comment: please be more clear and post screenshot if possible

Comment: Have you tried setting padding to 0 on the body and html?

Comment: @h3raldo yep tried, not helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set to your body margin to 0: `body {margin: 0;}`.

If you would like to keep this margin for the body, add the negative margin to the `header nav {margin: -8px;}`, but also remove from there `width: 100%;`.

Comment: No problem, this is the basic css knowledge, just try to inspect the website in developer tools for your favorite browser and play with styles for different tags. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

add `margin: 0;` to the body

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjj0Z.png)